# why define multiple module with same name in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new at angularjs. I am looking an application code.

```
<html> 
 .....
<script src="/my/app.main.js"></script>
<script src="/my/app.messages.js"></script>
<script src="/my/app.misc.js"></script>
<script src="/my/app.properties.js"></script>
```

and in these javascript filse icluding angularjs modules same name.

**main.js file**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('ngCookService');

    app.run([.....
        function (....) {            

        }]);
})();
```

**messages.js file**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module('ngCookService');

    app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) { 
       ................
    }]);
})();
```

All of these js files include **ngCookService** module. And modules defined in self-invoking functions.

How this system works? Does earlier defined modules overriding? or new defined **app** module kills earlier objects?

Answer (score 6):

When called with just the name of the module, `angular.module()` is a getter method and retrieves an existing module with that name. Therefore calling `angular.module('ngCookService')` does not override or replace the module.

For the getter to work, somewhere before it the setter must have been called. This is done by calling `angular.module()` with more than 1 argument (for example, a list of required modules)...

```
angular.module('ngCookService', ['ngRoute']);
```

If the setter is called more than once, then the module *is* being overridden.